# How to show the schema of a table include the constraints in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
describe table_name
```

doesn't show the constraints, Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DBMS_METADATA package, as [explained here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1794096300346327738).

Answer (score 0):

You can use system views. E.g. user_* or all_tab_columns and all_cons_columns.
Try like this:

```
SELECT tc.column_id, tc.table_name, tc.column_name, tc.data_type, cc.constraint_name 
  FROM user_tab_columns tc,
       user_cons_columns cc
WHERE  tc.table_name = cc.table_name(+)
  AND  tc.column_name = cc.column_name(+)
  AND  tc.table_name = 'YOU TABLE NAME THERE'
ORDER BY tc.column_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` view to see the table columns and it constraints.

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_cons_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```